# SQL Server Mail not reliable

Tags: sql-server, email, sqlmail

We have a SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition. I set up the SQL mail service (account + profile) on it a year ago, which worked perfectly (account: smtp.office365.com:587, SSL, basic auth).

Since October 11, 2021, there have been constant problems with sending mail. In many cases, sending mail doesn't work, I get the following error message:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2021-10-27T18: 07: 10). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).)

Here is an excerpt from the sysmail_allitems table:

[image: sysmail_allitems]

I don't understand what the problem is because the server sends the email once but not the other time.

Do you have any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Sending via office365, which has strict sending limits for raw smtp connections.

Comment: Yes, I know. The limit is 30 messages per minute, but I sent only 6 messages per minutes.